# Can't find phoenix 1.3 deps when deploying to heroku

Tags: heroku, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've run into this issue before, but can't recall how it was resolved.  I'm trying to push an phx 1.3 app to heroku for the first time, but I get an error:

```
remote:        npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/build_06158e99424e0327b7b56d1b5d95503a/deps/phoenix
remote:        npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/build_06158e99424e0327b7b56d1b5d95503a/deps/phoenix_html
```

I seem to recall that in v1.3 the file structure was changed.  My dependencies in `package.json` looks like:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html"
  },
```

*elixir_buildpack.config*:

`always_rebuild=true`

*phoenix_static_buildpack.config*:

```
assets_path=assets
phoenix_ex=phx
```

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Is `package.json` in the root folder? If so I think it should be `file:deps/phoenix`.

Comment: In 1.3, `package.json` is now under the Assets folder.

Comment: Is the `assets_path` relative to the `phoenix_relative_path`? — assuming this is an umbrella application